# Dual Banach space $X^*$ complemented in $\mathrm{Lip}_0(X)$?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, lipschitz-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator\Lip{Lip}$Let $X$ be a real Banach space. The dual $X^*$ is a closed subspace of $\Lip_0(X)$. ($\Lip_0(X)$ denotes the space of real-valued Lipschitz functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(0)=0$ with Lipschitz constant as norm).

Is there anything known about the complementability of $X^*$ inside $\Lip_0(X)$? If $X$ is finite dimensional, then $X^*$ is trivially complemented in $\Lip_0(X)$. Are there any examples of infinite dimensional spaces $X$ whose duals are or are not complemented in $\Lip_0(X)$?

Comment: When $X = L_1(\mu)$ (or more generally, $X$ is an abstract $\mathscr{L}_1$-space), then $X^*$ is injective hence complemented wherever embedded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Corollary 5.4 in my book (*Lipschitz Algebras*, 2nd edition): Let $V$ be a Banach space. Then there is a norm 1 linear projection from ${\rm Lip}_0(V)$ onto $V^*$. If $V$ is separable then there is a weak* continuous norm 1 linear projection.

This follows from Theorem 2 of "On nonlinear projections in Banach spaces" by Lindenstrauss (*Michigan Math J* **11** (1964), 263-287).

Comment: Thank you, Nik. I should have thought of checking the 2nd edition. I don't recall seeing this in 1st edition.

Comment: That's right, it's not in the 1st edition. (There's a lot more in the 2nd edition. It's twice as long!)